# How can I control what is shown in the notification bar in the package audio_service for FLutter

Tags: flutter, audio, notifications, slider, seekbar

I am trying to figure out where can I change what is shown in the notification bar in the audio_service package. More specifically, can you tell me where can I remove the slider (the seek bar) from the notification bar? ( it is not shown until you expand the bar ).
Or to improve it, by adding the current position and the max duration above it. But I think I can do that if I can find out where can I play around with the code for that.

My code is from ryanheise's example:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Audio Service Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: AudioServiceWidget(child: MainScreen()),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Tracks the position while the user drags the seek bar.
  final BehaviorSubject<double> _dragPositionSubject =
      BehaviorSubject.seeded(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Service Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
          stream: _screenStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final screenState = snapshot.data;
            final queue = screenState?.queue;
            final mediaItem = screenState?.mediaItem;
            
            final state = screenState?.playbackState;
            final processingState =
                state?.processingState ?? AudioProcessingState.none;
            final playing = state?.playing ?? false;
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.none) ...[
                  audioPlayerButton(),
                ] else ...[
                  if (queue != null && queue.isNotEmpty)
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                          iconSize: 64.0,
                          onPressed: mediaItem == queue.first
                              ? null
                              : AudioService.skipToPrevious,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                          iconSize: 64.0,
                          onPressed: mediaItem == queue.last
                              ? null
                              : AudioService.skipToNext,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  if (mediaItem?.title != null) Text(mediaItem.title),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      if (playing) pauseButton() else playButton(),
                      stopButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  positionIndicator(mediaItem, state),
                  Text("Processing state: " +
                      "$processingState".replaceAll(RegExp(r'^.*\.'), '')),
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: AudioService.customEventStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return Text("custom event: ${snapshot.data}");
                    },
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<bool>(
                    stream: AudioService.notificationClickEventStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return Text(
                        'Notification Click Status: ${snapshot.data}',
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Encapsulate all the different data we're interested in into a single
  /// stream so we don't have to nest StreamBuilders.
  Stream<ScreenState> get _screenStateStream =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, MediaItem, PlaybackState, ScreenState>(
          AudioService.queueStream,
          AudioService.currentMediaItemStream,
          AudioService.playbackStateStream,
          (queue, mediaItem, playbackState) =>
              ScreenState(queue, mediaItem, playbackState));

  RaisedButton audioPlayerButton() => startButton(
        'AudioPlayer',
        () {
          AudioService.start(
            backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
            androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Service Demo',
            // Enable this if you want the Android service to exit the foreground state on pause.
            //androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
            androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
            androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
            androidEnableQueue: true,
          );
        },
      );

  RaisedButton startButton(String label, VoidCallback onPressed) =>
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text(label),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );

  IconButton playButton() => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        iconSize: 64.0,
        onPressed: AudioService.play,
      );

  IconButton pauseButton() => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
        iconSize: 64.0,
        onPressed: AudioService.pause,
      );

  IconButton stopButton() => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
        iconSize: 64.0,
        onPressed: AudioService.stop,
      );

  Widget positionIndicator(MediaItem mediaItem, PlaybackState state) {
    double seekPos;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Rx.combineLatest2<double, double, double>(
          _dragPositionSubject.stream,
          Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200)),
          (dragPosition, _) => dragPosition),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        double position =
            snapshot.data ?? state.currentPosition.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
        double duration = mediaItem?.duration?.inMilliseconds?.toDouble();
        return Column(
          children: [
            if (duration != null)
              Slider(
                min: 0.0,
                max: duration,
                value: seekPos ?? max(0.0, min(position, duration)),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _dragPositionSubject.add(value);
                },
                onChangeEnd: (value) {
                  AudioService.seekTo(Duration(milliseconds: value.toInt()));
                  // Due to a delay in platform channel communication, there is
                  // a brief moment after releasing the Slider thumb before the
                  // new position is broadcast from the platform side. This
                  // hack is to hold onto seekPos until the next state update
                  // comes through.
                  // TODO: Improve this code.
                  seekPos = value;
                  _dragPositionSubject.add(null);
                },
              ),
            Text("${state.currentPosition}"),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ScreenState {
  final List<MediaItem> queue;
  final MediaItem mediaItem;
  final PlaybackState playbackState;

  ScreenState(this.queue, this.mediaItem, this.playbackState);
}

// NOTE: Your entrypoint MUST be a top-level function.
void _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint() async {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

/// This task defines logic for playing a list of podcast episodes.
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _mediaLibrary = MediaLibrary();
  AudioPlayer _player = new AudioPlayer();
  AudioProcessingState _skipState;
  Seeker _seeker;
  StreamSubscription<PlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;

  List<MediaItem> get queue => _mediaLibrary.items;
  int get index => _player.currentIndex;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => index == null ? null : queue[index];

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    // We configure the audio session for speech since we're playing a podcast.
    // You can also put this in your app's initialisation if your app doesn't
    // switch between two types of audio as this example does.
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
    // Broadcast media item changes.
    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      if (index != null) AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(queue[index]);
    });
    // Propagate all events from the audio player to AudioService clients.
    _eventSubscription = _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      _broadcastState();
    });
    // Special processing for state transitions.
    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      switch (state) {
        case ProcessingState.completed:
          // In this example, the service stops when reaching the end.
          onStop();
          break;
        case ProcessingState.ready:
          // If we just came from skipping between tracks, clear the skip
          // state now that we're ready to play.
          _skipState = null;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    // Load and broadcast the queue
    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
    try {
      await _player.load(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children:
            queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
      ));
      // In this example, we automatically start playing on start.
      onPlay();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      onStop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToQueueItem(String mediaId) async {
    // Then default implementations of onSkipToNext and onSkipToPrevious will
    // delegate to this method.
    final newIndex = queue.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaId);
    if (newIndex == -1) return;
    // During a skip, the player may enter the buffering state. We could just
    // propagate that state directly to AudioService clients but AudioService
    // has some more specific states we could use for skipping to next and
    // previous. This variable holds the preferred state to send instead of
    // buffering during a skip, and it is cleared as soon as the player exits
    // buffering (see the listener in onStart).
    _skipState = newIndex > index
        ? AudioProcessingState.skippingToNext
        : AudioProcessingState.skippingToPrevious;
    // This jumps to the beginning of the queue item at newIndex.
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onPlay() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> onPause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekTo(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() => _seekRelative(fastForwardInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() => _seekRelative(-rewindInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekForward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, 1);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekBackward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, -1);

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _player.pause();
    await _player.dispose();
    _eventSubscription.cancel();
    // It is important to wait for this state to be broadcast before we shut
    // down the task. If we don't, the background task will be destroyed before
    // the message gets sent to the UI.
    await _broadcastState();
    // Shut down this task
    await super.onStop();
  }

  /// Jumps away from the current position by [offset].
  Future<void> _seekRelative(Duration offset) async {
    var newPosition = _player.position + offset;
    // Make sure we don't jump out of bounds.
    if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
    if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
    // Perform the jump via a seek.
    await _player.seek(newPosition);
  }

  /// Begins or stops a continuous seek in [direction]. After it begins it will
  /// continue seeking forward or backward by 10 seconds within the audio, at
  /// intervals of 1 second in app time.
  void _seekContinuously(bool begin, int direction) {
    _seeker?.stop();
    if (begin) {
      _seeker = Seeker(_player, Duration(seconds: 10 * direction),
          Duration(seconds: 1), mediaItem)
        ..start();
    }
  }

  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.
  Future<void> _broadcastState() async {
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: [
        MediaAction.play,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      ],
      processingState: _getProcessingState(),
      playing: _player.playing,
      position: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
    );
  }

  /// Maps just_audio's processing state into into audio_service's playing
  /// state. If we are in the middle of a skip, we use [_skipState] instead.
  AudioProcessingState _getProcessingState() {
    if (_skipState != null) return _skipState;
    switch (_player.processingState) {
      case ProcessingState.none:
        return AudioProcessingState.stopped;
      case ProcessingState.loading:
        return AudioProcessingState.connecting;
      case ProcessingState.buffering:
        return AudioProcessingState.buffering;
      case ProcessingState.ready:
        return AudioProcessingState.ready;
      case ProcessingState.completed:
        return AudioProcessingState.completed;
      default:
        throw Exception("Invalid state: ${_player.processingState}");
    }
  }
}

/// Provides access to a library of media items. In your app, this could come
/// from a database or web service.
class MediaLibrary {
  final _items = <MediaItem>[
    MediaItem(
      id: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3",
      album: "Science Friday",
      title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
      artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
      artUri:
          "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
    ),
    MediaItem(
      id: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3",
      album: "Science Friday",
      title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
      artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2856950),
      artUri:
          "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
    ),
  ];

  List<MediaItem> get items => _items;
}

/// An object that performs interruptable sleep.
class Sleeper {
  Completer _blockingCompleter;

  /// Sleep for a duration. If sleep is interrupted, a
  /// [SleeperInterruptedException] will be thrown.
  Future<void> sleep([Duration duration]) async {
    _blockingCompleter = Completer();
    if (duration != null) {
      await Future.any([Future.delayed(duration), _blockingCompleter.future]);
    } else {
      await _blockingCompleter.future;
    }
    final interrupted = _blockingCompleter.isCompleted;
    _blockingCompleter = null;
    if (interrupted) {
      throw SleeperInterruptedException();
    }
  }

  /// Interrupt any sleep that's underway.
  void interrupt() {
    if (_blockingCompleter?.isCompleted == false) {
      _blockingCompleter.complete();
    }
  }
}

class SleeperInterruptedException {}

/// A wrapper around FlutterTts that makes it easier to wait for speech to
/// complete.

class Seeker {
  final AudioPlayer player;
  final Duration positionInterval;
  final Duration stepInterval;
  final MediaItem mediaItem;
  bool _running = false;

  Seeker(
    this.player,
    this.positionInterval,
    this.stepInterval,
    this.mediaItem,
  );

  start() async {
    _running = true;
    while (_running) {
      Duration newPosition = player.position + positionInterval;
      if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
      if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
      player.seek(newPosition);
      await Future.delayed(stepInterval);
    }
  }

  stop() {
    _running = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example should already display the current position and duration below the seek bar, and it does this by calling `AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem` (0.17) or `AudioHandler.mediaItem.add` (0.18) to set the duration, and calling `AudioServiceBackground.setState` (0.17) or `AudioHandler.playbackState.add` (0.18) to set the current position. You cannot influence where it is displayed as this is chosen by the operating system, but it is typically below the seek bar, not above, for both Android and iOS.

In 0.17, you can remove the seek bar by removing the `seekTo` media action from the `systemActions` parameter of `AudioServiceBackground.setState` which it appears you have already done. From the [setState documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/0.17.1/audio_service/AudioServiceBackground/setState.html):

> Any other action you would like to enable for clients that is not a
> clickable notification button should be specified in the
> systemActions parameter. For example:
>
> - MediaAction.seekTo (enable a seek bar)

In 0.18, you do the same by removing the `seek` media action from the `systemActions` parameter of `PlaybackState`. From the [PlaybackState documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/latest/audio_service/PlaybackState/systemActions.html):

> Note that specifying [MediaAction.seek] in [systemActions] will enable a
> seek bar in both the Android notification and the iOS control center, but
> on Android, it will show only if the media item's duration has been set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry in addition, I cannot figure out how to format a comment :(
Well, I played a bit with the code, but it seems that if I remove the seekTo mediaAction it does not remove the seekbar. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other place where I have to remove it?

I did it like this:        

...
`
await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
controls: [ ...],
systemActions:[
// MediaAction.seekTo,
//MediaAction.seekForward,
//MediaAction.seekBackward, ],
`

Comment: I think there is a problem with only my phone, I've tried on a emulator pixel 3 and there, the seek bar is not shown. So maybe a bug for the S9. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you should remove "duration"  in mediaitem too